# How to use the which function to determine the rows that contain exactly two occurrences of the number 1?

Tags: r, matrix

Using the `sample.int` function to create `M` as a 6x10 matrix of random integers chosen from {1, 2, ..., 10}, I would like to know how to use the which function to determine the rows that contain exactly 2 occurrences of the number 1.

```
M <- matrix(sample.int(10, size=6*10, replace=TRUE), nrow = 6, ncol = 10)
```

I require that the answer be only ONE line of R code (you can call multiple functions in 1 line, of course!).

I tried `length(which(M == 1))`. That computes the number of elements that match the value 1. My second attempt was to solve the problem using nested `for` loops, but I was not able to reduce the solution to one line. I do not know if there is an API function call that would simplify things.

Comment: For homework, you are expected to show what you have tried.  Please see [how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I have edited the question to show the solutions I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
which(rowSums(M == 1) == 2)
```

`M == 1` gives a logical matrix with `TRUE` where `M` contains 1, then `rowSums` gives the number of ones in each row, and `which` gives the result.